# pclose and waitpid fail when used in a daemonized process on a crosscompiled device

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, pipe, daemon

I'm fairly new to C++ programming and have only been lurking here on SO but I've run into an issue when trying to write a program that will be crosscompiled and executed on an embedded system and hope someone more knowledable might be able to help me.

The goal of my program A is to allow another program B on said embedded system to execute different tasks and get system information as well as my program A being a watchdog for the program B. This means my program A has to run as a daemon as it's supposed to constantly monitor and interact with program B. All these tasks and the gathering of information is supposed to run in their own thread each to prevent program A from blocking or hanging if a task takes some time or something similar. I have been using `async()` and `futures` to accomplish that.

One of the tasks is to allow program B to execute shell commands and get the output of those commands back. So far this works in my program. I've been using the functionality of `popen` and `pclose` to create a pipe and get the result of the executed shell command.

My next goal was to try tell program B if the shell command executed by program A failed or succeeded. From the information I could find online `pclose()` returns the exit code of the underlying pipe or returns -1 if something within `pclose()` failed.

To demo all this I wrote a small testing program an I was able to successfully get the return code from `pclose()`. But when I integrated my small demo program into the main program I ran into some issues as `pclose()` always returns -1 regardless of if the command succeeds or fails.

I read online that `popen()` and `pclose()` are not really considered thread safe and so I looked around to implement my own version of this functionality, simplified down to my needs using `pipe`, `fork` and the `exec*` family of functions. (In my `main.cpp` below you can find both the version with the regular `popen()` and `pclose()` "runCommandDefaultPopen()" as well as my simplified own implementation "runCommandCustomPopen()")

But my own implementation didn't fix the issues and it seemed like `waitpid` didn't even interact with the return code variable provided so I tried around some other stuff and quickly narrowed it down to the issue being the daemonizing of the program. I attached the `daemonize.h` and `daemonize.cpp` files below. Without daemonizing the process my program works as expected so I assume something breaks when detaching the process. Possibly some signals are not handled correctly or I'm missing a vital step when daemonizing my process.

Sadly I don't know what I'm doing wrong, if I'm missing something or if this is just an edge case that's not supported and I should be using some other means of implementing this functionality.

### Daemonized code

My `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/syslog.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

#include "daemonize.h"

const int READ = 0;
const int WRITE = 1;

int runCommandCustomPopen(std::string command) {

  pid_t child_pid;
  int rc = -999;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  if ((child_pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* here the child begins */
  if (child_pid == 0) {
    /* redirect stdout to pipe */
    close(fd[READ]);
    dup2(fd[WRITE], 1);
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL);
  } else {
    close(fd[WRITE]);
  }

  close(fd[WRITE]);
  while (waitpid(child_pid, &rc, 0) == 0) {
    if (errno != EINTR) {
      rc = -1;
      break;
    }
  }
  /* Read in the pipe and save the content to a buffer */
  std::array<char, 16> buffer;
  std::string commandResult;

  FILE *fdd = fdopen(fd[READ], "r");
  while (::fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), fdd) != nullptr) {
    commandResult += buffer.data();
  }

  syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Command result is: %s", commandResult.c_str());

  return rc;
}

int runCommandDefaultPopen(std::string command) {
  int rc = -999; // the return code variable
  std::array<char, 16> buffer;
  std::string commandResult;

  // A wrapper function to be able to get the return code while still using the
  // automatic close function wizardy of unique_ptr
  auto pclose_wrapper = [&rc](FILE *cmd) { rc = ::pclose(cmd); };
  {
    const std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(pclose_wrapper)> pipe(
        ::popen(command.c_str(), "r"), pclose_wrapper);

    if (!pipe) {
      throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed and could not run the command");
    }

    /* Read in the pipe and save the content to a buffer */
    while (::fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
      commandResult += buffer.data();
    }
  }
  syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Command result is: %s", commandResult.c_str());

  return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // Daemonize process
  bool rd = true;
  std::string pidfile = "/tmp/testing.pid";
  daemonize(&rd, pidfile);

  // some test command
  std::string cmd = "ls /var/bla/; sleep 2; echo test";

  // Test the functions with futurs and "standalone"/blocking
  std::future<int> _fut, _fut2;

  syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandCustomPopen no async: %d", runCommandCustomPopen(cmd));

  _fut = std::async(std::launch::async, runCommandCustomPopen, cmd);
  _fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, runCommandDefaultPopen, cmd);

  while (rd) {

    if (_fut.valid() &&
        _fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
      syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandCustomPopen: %d", _fut.get());
    }

    if (_fut2.valid() &&
        _fut2.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
      syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandDefaultPopen: %d", _fut2.get());
    }
    syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "waiting...");
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(100));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

My `daemonize.h`:

```cpp
#ifndef DAEMONIZE_H_
#define DAEMONIZE_H_

#include <string>

void daemonize(bool *rundaemon, std::string pidFilePath);

#endif /* DAEMONIZE_H_ */
```

My `daemonize.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <syslog.h>
#include <unistd.h>

/* declare helper methods */
void signalHandler(int sig);
void createPidFile(std::string pidFilePath);

/* global variables */
bool *_p_rundaemon;

void daemonize(bool *rundaemon, std::string pidFilePath) {
  pid_t pid;
  struct sigaction newSigAction;

  _p_rundaemon = rundaemon;

  /* Fork off the parent process */
  pid = fork();

  /* An error occurred */
  if (pid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  /* Success: Let the parent terminate */
  if (pid > 0)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  /* On success: The child process becomes session leader */
  if (setsid() < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  /* Catch, ignore and handle signals */
  signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);

  /* Set up a signal handler */
  newSigAction.sa_handler = signalHandler;
  sigemptyset(&newSigAction.sa_mask);
  newSigAction.sa_flags = 0;

  /* Signals to handle */
  sigaction(SIGHUP, &newSigAction, NULL);  /* catch hangup signal */
  sigaction(SIGTERM, &newSigAction, NULL); /* catch term signal */
  sigaction(SIGINT, &newSigAction, NULL);  /* catch interrupt signal */

  /* Fork off for the second time*/
  pid = fork();

  /* An error occurred */
  if (pid < 0)
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);

  /* Success: Let the parent terminate */
  if (pid > 0)
    exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);

  /* Set new file permissions */
  umask(0);

  /* Change the working directory to the root directory */
  /* or another appropriate directory */
  chdir("/");

  /* Close all open file descriptors */
  int x;
  for (x = sysconf(_SC_OPEN_MAX); x >= 0; x--) {
    close(x);
  }

  createPidFile(pidFilePath);
}

void signalHandler(int sig) {
  switch (sig) {
  case SIGINT:
  case SIGTERM:
    *_p_rundaemon = false;
    break;
  }
}

void createPidFile(std::string pidFilePath) {
  /* Ensure only one copy */
  int pidFilehandle = open(pidFilePath.c_str(), O_RDWR | O_CREAT, 0600);

  if (pidFilehandle == -1) {
    /* Couldn't open lock file */
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Could not open PID lock file %s, exiting",
           pidFilePath.c_str());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Try to lock file */
  if (lockf(pidFilehandle, F_TLOCK, 0) == -1) {
    /* Couldn't get lock on lock file */
    syslog(LOG_WARNING, "Could not lock PID lock file %s, exiting",
           pidFilePath.c_str());
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  /* Get and format PID */
  std::string pid = std::to_string(getpid());

  /* write pid to lockfile */
  write(pidFilehandle, pid.c_str(), pid.length());

  syslog(LOG_INFO, "Createded PID lock file %s for process %s",
         pidFilePath.c_str(), pid.c_str());
}
```

##### Compile

`$CXX main.cpp daemonize.cpp -o pcloseTest -Wall -Werror -pthread`
With `$CXX` being my arm-crosscompiler in my cross compile toolchain

##### Output

Here is the output of `/var/log/messages` from the embedded system with the program running as daemonized process:

```
May  9 09:55:38 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.info MyDemoProg[9988]: Createded PID lock file /tmp/testing.pid for process 9988
May  9 09:55:40 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: Command result is: test
May  9 09:55:40 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: runCommandCustomPopen no async: -999
May  9 09:55:40 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:40 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:41 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:41 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: Command result is: test
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: Command result is: test
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: runCommandCustomPopen: -999
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: runCommandDefaultPopen: -1
May  9 09:55:42 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:43 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:43 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
May  9 09:55:44 MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM daemon.debug MyDemoProg[9988]: waiting...
```

As you can see when daemonizing the process the default `popen()` and `pclose()` return -1 and the custom one does not change the inital value of the variable `rc`.

### Non-daemonized code

Here is the same code but able to run as a regular programm in the commandline (main2.cpp):

```cpp
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>
#include <string>
#include <sys/stat.h>
//#include <sys/syslog.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <thread>
#include <unistd.h>

//#include "daemonize.h"

const int READ = 0;
const int WRITE = 1;

int runCommandCustomPopen(std::string command) {

  pid_t child_pid;
  int rc = -999;
  int fd[2];
  pipe(fd);
  if ((child_pid = fork()) == -1) {
    perror("fork");
    exit(1);
  }
  /* here the child begins */
  if (child_pid == 0) {
    /* redirect stdout to pipe */
    close(fd[READ]);
    dup2(fd[WRITE], 1);
    execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", command.c_str(), NULL);
  } else {
    close(fd[WRITE]);
  }

  close(fd[WRITE]);
  while (waitpid(child_pid, &rc, 0) == 0) {
    if (errno != EINTR) {
      rc = -1;
      break;
    }
  }
  /* Read in the pipe and save the content to a buffer */
  std::array<char, 16> buffer;
  std::string commandResult;

  FILE *fdd = fdopen(fd[READ], "r");
  while (::fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), fdd) != nullptr) {
    commandResult += buffer.data();
  }

  // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Command result is: %s", commandResult.c_str());
  std::cout << "Command result is: " << commandResult << std::endl;

  return rc;
}

int runCommandDefaultPopen(std::string command) {
  int rc = -999; // the return code variable
  std::array<char, 16> buffer;
  std::string commandResult;

  // A wrapper function to be able to get the return code while still using the
  // automatic close function wizardy of unique_ptr
  auto pclose_wrapper = [&rc](FILE *cmd) { rc = ::pclose(cmd); };
  {
    const std::unique_ptr<FILE, decltype(pclose_wrapper)> pipe(
        ::popen(command.c_str(), "r"), pclose_wrapper);

    if (!pipe) {
      throw std::runtime_error("popen() failed and could not run the command");
    }

    /* Read in the pipe and save the content to a buffer */
    while (::fgets(buffer.data(), buffer.size(), pipe.get()) != nullptr) {
      commandResult += buffer.data();
    }
  }
  // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "Command result is: %s", commandResult.c_str());
  std::cout << "Command result is: " << commandResult << std::endl;

  return rc;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  // setlogmask(LOG_UPTO(LOG_DEBUG));
  // openlog("MyDemoProg", LOG_PID, LOG_DAEMON);

  // bool rd = true;
  // std::string pidfile = "/tmp/testing.pid";

  // daemonize(&rd, pidfile);

  std::string cmd = "ls /var/bla/; sleep 2; echo test";

  std::future<int> _fut, _fut2;

  // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandCustomPopen no async: %d",
  // runCommandCustomPopen(cmd));
  std::cout << "runCommandCustomPopen no async: " << runCommandCustomPopen(cmd)
            << std::endl;

  _fut = std::async(std::launch::async, runCommandCustomPopen, cmd);
  _fut2 = std::async(std::launch::async, runCommandDefaultPopen, cmd);

  // while (rd) {
  while (true) {

    if (_fut.valid() &&
        _fut.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
      // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandCustomPopen: %d", _fut.get());
      std::cout << "runCommandCustomPopen: " << _fut.get() << std::endl;
    }

    if (_fut2.valid() &&
        _fut2.wait_for(std::chrono::seconds(0)) == std::future_status::ready) {
      // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "runCommandDefaultPopen: %d", _fut2.get());
      std::cout << "runCommandDefaultPopen: " << _fut2.get() << std::endl;
    }
    // syslog(LOG_DEBUG, "waiting...");
    std::cout << "waiting..." << std::endl;
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));
  }
  return 0;
}
```

##### Compile

`$CXX main2.cpp -o pcloseTest2 -Wall -Werror -pthread`
With `$CXX` being my arm-crosscompiler in my cross compile toolchain

##### Output

And here the corresponding output from the commandline where all commands - async or not - return the expected 0 to signal they succeeded.

```
root@MY-EMBEDDED-SYSTEM:~# /opt/tmp/pcloseTest2
ls: cannot access '/var/bla/': No such file or directory
runCommandCustomPopen no async: Command result is: test

0
waiting...
ls: cannot access '/var/bla/': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/var/bla/': No such file or directory
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
Command result is: test

Command result is: test

runCommandCustomPopen: 0
runCommandDefaultPopen: 0
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
waiting...
^C
```

I hope this gives an insight into what I'm trying to do and maybe someone has an idea on how to resolve this issue and get the correct return value from the forked process so I can handle the execution of the command better.

Thank you so much in advance! If any further information are needed or more details need to be given let me know!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). Lastly please learn how to create a [mre], with emphasis on the *minimal* part.

Comment: Hello @Someprogrammerdude. Thank you for your feedback. I'll try to break the whole question down and rephrase it as well as make the whole example more compact.